# How to send non-string data across activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, twitter4j

In twitterfragment class I have

```
List<twitter4j.Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(user);
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), twitter_timeline.class);
intent.putExtra(twitter_timeline.STATUS_LIST, statuses);// this line giving error if I pass status
```

In twitter_timeline class I want to get the statues I sent from twitter fragment.

```
public class twitter_timeline extends Activity {
    public static List<twitter4j.Status> STATUS_LIST;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter_timeline);

        setTitle("Timeline");

        List<twitter4j.Status> statuses = (Status) this.getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(STATUS_LIST); // this line not resolving even if I cast it to status type
    }
```

Here intent expects to get StringArray in the function getIntent.getStringArrayExtra(...), but I have sent Twitter Status from my fragment.

Comment: Use EventBus from green robots. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: obviously your status is not a string array, so why do you call getStringArray?

Comment: to show what I want the statement to work like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the [twitter4j.Status](http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/4.0.2/twitter4j/Status.html) class implements Serializable, you should be able to create a Serializable wrapper class and send that through the Intent Extras.

Create a MyStatuses class in MyStatuses.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyStatuses implements Serializable {
    List<twitter4j.Status> statuses;
}
```

Then send an instance of the wrapper class in the Intent Extras:

```
    List<twitter4j.Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(user);
    MyStatuses myStatuses = new MyStatuses();
    myStatuses.statuses = statuses;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), twitter_timeline.class);
    intent.putExtra("statuses", myStatuses);
```

Then use getSerializable() in order to get the Intent Extra:

```
public class twitter_timeline extends Activity {
    //public static List<twitter4j.Status> STATUS_LIST; 
    List<twitter4j.Status> statuses;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter_timeline);

        setTitle("Timeline");
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            MyStatuses myStatuses = (MyStatuses) b.getSerializable("statuses");
            statuses = myStatuses.statuses;
        }
    }
```